# How to parameterize date format in Postman tool for testing

Tags: postman

Below format is in the body

```
"dateOfBirth":"[
1980,
6,
5
]",
```

I have to parameterize (has to Change for each iteration(using CSV file)).

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this should be tagged postman not java no?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you have 2 options :

1. You can separate it in your CSV data file like:
   `dateOfBirthYear,dateOfBirthDay,dateOfBirthMonth
   1980,6,5 //1st iteration 
   1981,10,11 //2nd iteration etc.
   ...`
2. You can use JSON instead, like:

`[
   { //here first iteration starts
     "dateOfBirth":
       [
       1980,
       6,
       5
       ],
     "someOtherData: "string"
   },//here is the end of 1st iteration
   {//here second iteration starts
      "dateOfBirth":
       [
       1980,
       6,
       5
       ],
       "someOtherData: "string"
   }//here is the end of 2st iteration
]`
(comments are not allowed in JSON)

then you can use it in pre-request script:

`var dateArray = data.dateOfBirth`
but don't forget that such syntax doesn't work : `{{data.dateOfBirth[1]}}` (in Url f.e)

Comment: We are able to parameterize using JSON file.Thanks for your response :-)